# Dynamic fields in django forms

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to have a custom form on django admin for my ModelB, with fields taken from other ModelA.

**models.py**

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    source = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    keys = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=50)
    )

class ModelB(models.Model):
    characteristic_keys = JSONField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class ModelBForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        queryset = ModelA.objects.all()
        dynamic_fields = [(x.source, x.keys) for x in queryset]

        # New fields to be shown on admin =>
        # Field name => "source" from modelA
        # Field type => multiple choice with options => "keys" from modelA

        for field in dynamic_fields:
            self.fields[field[0]] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                         choices=field[1])

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # ...do something with extra_field here...
        return super().save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        model = Workflow
        fields = "__all__"
```

**admin.py**

```
class ModelBAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ModelBForm

admin.site.register(ModelB, ModelBAdmin)
```

I want a single form for ModelB on django admin, with dynamic "source" fields takes from ModelA, with multiple choice options from their corresponding "key" values in modelB.

I have tried to keep information clear and understandable, please let me know if I have missed any information that might be needed to understand the problem. Any ideas to deal this problem would be a great help!

Comment: Is there a reason for not using a many to many relationship between the two models?

Comment: Yeah, one source may have many keys, and modelB can need only few keys of some of the sources. This is the simplest design we have reduced everything to.